# How to solve that error msg 'Unable to initialize any output collector'?

Tags: hadoop

I make simple map-redue program using hadoop api. However, I met some error message when Hadoop machine did mapredue job. How to solve it??

ps. I use hadoop 2.6.0

> {"type":"MAP_ATTEMPT_FAILED","event":{"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.TaskAttemptUnsuccessfulCompletion":{"taskid":"task_1438070830862_0003_m_000002","taskType":"MAP","attemptId":"attempt_1438070830862_0003_m_000002_0","finishTime":1438760025042,"hostname":"HADOOP-NODE7","port":56135,"rackname":"/default-rack","status":"FAILED","error":"Error: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize any output collector\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:695)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)\n","counters":{"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JhCounters":{"name":"COUNTERS","groups":[{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter","displayName":"Map-Reduce Framework","counts":[{"name":"SPILLED_RECORDS","displayName":"Spilled Records","value":0},{"name":"FAILED_SHUFFLE","displayName":"Failed Shuffles","value":0},{"name":"MERGED_MAP_OUTPUTS","displayName":"Merged Map outputs","value":0},{"name":"CPU_MILLISECONDS","displayName":"CPU time spent (ms)","value":0},{"name":"PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES","displayName":"Physical memory (bytes) snapshot","value":0},{"name":"VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES","displayName":"Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot","value":0}]}]}},"clockSplits":[104143,11,11,11,11,11,10,11,11,11,11,11],"cpuUsages":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"vMemKbytes":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"physMemKbytes":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}}}

Comment: It would be great if u share your code. Going by the log i guess u have messed up with older and newer Api